# Checking a loadable JNI Library

Tags: java, java-native-interface, classloader

I have a question. Is there a way by which I can check if a dll can be loaded without actually loading it? My problem is as follows:

I am using a Third party API that needs to load a native library. But the weird thing is that despite being a "Library" it will make a call to `System.exit()` if it cannot load the native library. Although my application depends on that library, I do not want my application to crash even if I cannot use the library which is only a feature in my application [albeit an important one]. So before I use the library, I want to check if the dll is loadable. I tried to do this by making an check if an UnsatisfiedLinkError was thrown from the statement `System.loadLibrary("LibraryName")`. If an error was thrown then I do not use that library. However If it does not throw any error I go with using the library. Now after doing this I get the following error:

> Cannot native library. The libary was
>   already loaded in a different
>   ClassLoader.

Hance I cannot load the library from the `System.loadLibrary()` method and do it only from the Third Party library.
So, my question is "How can I check if a library is loadable without actually loading it?"

Answer (score 0):

If a library cannot be loaded, it shouldn't call system.exit().  When ever I attempt to load a library whichc annot be loaded, I get an error. Is it possible that your library which is not loading correctly is killing the process.  The only way to check for this is to have a seperate process attempt to load the library and see what happens.

Comment: I am using a third party library [as a .jar file]. That jar has a class that loads a native library. But if there were any errors during the loading of the library it calls System.exit(); Also to use the library I have to make the jar load the native library itself. If I do it for him, it gives me errors.

Comment: You can use the SecurityManager to prevent the library performing a System.exit() You could use it to set a flag instead to say the library failed to load.

Comment: How can I use the SecurityManager to prevent the library from doing System.exit()?